# How to build an object within an object c#

Tags: c#

I need an object within an object. the "main" object needs 3 string fields and 1 field of an object that contains another string.
I figured out that I have to create 2 class one with 3 string fields and the other object and one with one string field.
now my question how do I get the second class as an object in the first class?

Comment: Which language are you using, C or C#?  They're very different.

Comment: Why is this question tagged with two very different languages?

Comment: There are plenty of other questions asking this already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the question title says C#, let's go with that, and use some syntax sugar:

```
using System;

namespace Example
{

    public class Child
    {
        public string Property1 { get; set; }
    }

    public class Parent
    {
        public string Property1 { get; set; }
        public string Property2 { get; set; }
        public string Property3 { get; set; }
        public Child Property4 { get; set; }
    }

    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var foo = new Parent
            {
                Property1 = "Hi",
                Property2 = "there",
                Property3 = "Svenja",
                Property4 = new Child
                {
                    Property1 = "Löffel"
                }
            };
            Console.WriteLine(foo.Property3);
            Console.WriteLine(foo.Property4.Property1);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

[Working Fiddle here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/8UCAbC).

Answer (score 3):

You add a property or field to the first object whose type is that of the second object e.g.

```
public class ChildObject
{
    public string ChildObjectProperty1 {get; set;}
}

public class MainObject
{
    public string Property1 {get; set;}
    public string Property2 {get; set;}
    public string Property3 {get; set;}
    public ChildObject Property4 {get; set;}
    public MainObject()
    {
        // Initialize Property4 to a new instance of a ChildObject
        this.Property4 = new ChildObject();
    }
}
```

Comment: That's C#, by the way, not C.